# Slow TypeScript autocompletion in VS Code for Zod

Tags: node.js, typescript, performance, autocomplete

I have a simple project set up in TypeScript. I'm using Prisma to connect with the database, express for HTTP server and Zod for validation of the request bodies. I'm also using eslint, which runs on every file save. While typing code, the suggestions take about 2-3 seconds to load, which has become very annoying and it doesn't seem like a normal behavior to me.

For example: it takes usually about ~2 seconds to load the suggestions for an object parsed with Zod schema or load the suggestions for the Prisma Client. I'm not sure if that's strictly the Zod/Prisma issue, although I opened this project in Webstorm and the same issue occured, maybe it was slightly faster but still a significant delay was visible. What I tried with no success:

- opening the project on a different machine
- disabling all extensions
- reinstalling VS Code
- installing older versions of VS Code
- using different versions of TypeScript compiler

Example:

[image: Loading autocompletion]

Part of the **TS Server Log**:

```
...
Info 277  [21:17:19.421] getCompletionData: Get current token: 0.012008000165224075
Info 278  [21:17:19.421] getCompletionData: Is inside comment: 0.028876000083982944
Info 279  [21:17:19.421] getCompletionData: Get previous token: 0.024034999776631594
Info 280  [21:17:19.421] getCompletionsAtPosition: isCompletionListBlocker: 0.131608999799937
Info 281  [21:17:21.381] getCompletionData: Semantic work: 1959.9019869999029
Info 282  [21:17:21.388] getCompletionsAtPosition: getCompletionEntriesFromSymbols: 5.953261999879032
Info 283  [21:17:21.733] IntelliCode plugin: successfully loaded model from /home/xkcm/.vscode/extensions/visualstudioexptteam.vscodeintellicode-1.2.29/dist/bundledModels/javascript_intellisense-members
...
```

As you can see the `getCompletionData` action takes about 2 seconds to finish. I'll also attach my configuration for typescript and eslint.

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "target": "ES2015",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

**.eslintrc.cjs**

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    "airbnb-base",
    "airbnb-typescript/base"
  ],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
  root: true,
  ignorePatterns: [
    ".eslintrc.cjs",
    "dist/**/*",
    "node_modules/**/*"
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    project: "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/quotes": ["error", "double"],
    "curly": ["error", "all"],
    "no-console": ["error", { allow: ["info", "warn", "error"] }],
    "no-use-before-define": ["error", { functions: false, classes: false }],
    "@typescript-eslint/brace-style": ["error", "1tbs", { allowSingleLine: false }],
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "max-classes-per-file": "off"
  }
};
```

Also my list of dependencies in the project:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^4.8.0",
    "chalk": "4.1.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "winston": "^3.8.2",
    "zod": "^3.20.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.15",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.191",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.17",
    "@types/winston": "^2.4.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.46.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.46.1",
    "dotenv-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.30.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "prisma": "^4.7.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  }
```

My environment:

- VS Code: 1.74.2-1671533413
- TypeScript: 4.9.4
- Node: v16.13.1

Is this a normal behavior? Does anyone know why this is happening? It'd be great if I could at least understand why it takes so long. This has become really frustrating, any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

**Edit**: I noticed my CPU usage spikes to 100% when autocompletion is loading, could this be a TypeScript issue?

**Edit 2**: I removed the `zod` package and the issue seems to be gone, very strange. Related issue in TypeScript repo: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45824

**Edit 3**: I discovered that downgrading the `zod` package to `v3.19.1` also fixes the issue. There's an issue opened on their GitHub about performance problems with `v3.20.2`: https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/1741

Comment: had the same issue with zod@3.20.2, downgraded to 3.19.1, its better but still takes time or getting stuck

Comment: Zod creator here. This is fixed in Zod 3.21, I encourage everyone to upgrade. Apologies for the inconvenience. 

A 6-character change causes an infinite recursion in the TS compiler: https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/pull/1617. Zod uses a lot of tricks to avoid recursive types but this one snuck in. I'll incorporate `tsc` build times into the test suite to avoid regressions like this in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`zod@3.20.2` caused this issue, downgrading to `3.19.1` fixed it.

Comment: Zod creator here. This is fixed in Zod 3.21, I encourage everyone to upgrade. Apologies for the inconvenience. 

A 6-character change causes an infinite recursion in the TS compiler: https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/pull/1617. Zod uses a lot of tricks to avoid recursive types but this one snuck in. I'll incorporate `tsc` build times into the test suite to avoid regressions like this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

in `tsconfig.json` add `compilerOptions.strict = true`

its work for me